# Unity shader glitches according to the Dark Mode on iOS 15

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm using a shader (code below) which allows me to turn an image color into a grayscale (with transparency if needed).

Everything was perfect until I updated my device to iOS 15. Since that update, my shaders glitch as soon as the scene is rendered.
After a lot of days searching for a solution, I noticed that this is related to the iPhone Dark Mode.

I provided here some "concept" example in order to show you what currently happens:

[image]

The Grayscale shader is applied onto a red cube.

- The cube **A** runs on an iPhone with Dark Mode activated (which is the result I get in Unity, the correct one).
- The cube **B** represents the same object with Dark Mode disabled.

The problem is that I've been using these shaders for a lot of items inside my application and this gives me an inconsistency and ugly UI according to the User's Dark Mode preferences.

**Note**: I don't think that the problem is the shader itself, because on the < iOS 15 version it works fine. I think is something about how iOS 15 handles shaders with transparency effects, but It's just a supposition 'cause I still don't know how to work with shaders (I'm a student).

This is the shader I'm using:

```
Shader "Unlit/NewUnlitShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _EffectAmount ("Effect Amount", Range (0, 1)) = 1.0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
        }

        LOD 200
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    
        Pass
        {

        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            uniform float _EffectAmount;
            
            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }
            
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                c.rgb = lerp(c.rgb, dot(c.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11)), _EffectAmount);
                return c;
            }

        ENDCG
        }
    }
    Fallback "Standard"
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**UPDATE - SOLVE**

It's a bug, Unity devs have been notified about this.

Comment: I have similar bug for transparent objects on iOS 14.8.1. Unity 2020.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"shader works < iOS 15" doesn't mean the shader itself is always correct.**

Some simple shader variable types like float, half, and fixed can give you total different result in different devices and OS.

"half" and "fixed" variables for better performance, while "float" for less bug.

It happens mostly on mobile, due to different CPU/GPU specs and also your Graphic APIs option.

Another key word will be "Color Space", please check Linear & Gamma option in your Unity Build Player settings.

**A broken shader will return pink color. If it's not pink, it must be some math issue in your shader for wrong result.**
The shader code works very straight forwarding. If the rendering result changes after a while, it seems likely some variables are changed in runtime too. And obviously the plugin which you are using, is also included lots of math calculation between C# and Shader.

**You can imagine this:**
When the C# code is trying to get variable from Shader, but shader return a wrong variable for your calculation in C#. Then, C# assign the wrong calculation result again to the Shader.
This will become infinite loop for wrong result.

**Unity UI Effects(with shader) are not reliable:**
Sometimes, they are just not updated... You have to force them update via script. Below commands may help sometimes, but not always...

```
Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
ScrollRect.GraphicUpdateComplete();
```

**Thus, you should contact the developer who maintain this plugin instead. As they know the best of how their plugin works**

Otherwise, you should begin writing your own shader scripts instead.
Grayscale shader is just extremely easy to write..

**Edit 2021-12-07:**

From your shader, I can't see any relationship between greyscale and alpha channel.

```
 c.rgb = lerp(c.rgb, dot(c.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11)), _EffectAmount);
```

I think this would be a proper way to achieve what you needed.

```
fixed3 greyColor = dot(c.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));
c.rgb = lerp(c.rgb, greyColor, _EffectAmount);
c.a = greyColor.a;
```

Meanwhile, removing the line "Fallback..." should help debugging. As sometimes the fallback shader will override your current shader scripts.

```
Fallback "Standard"//remove it<---
```

There is also a mis-matching variable type in your original code, it should be float2 instead of half2.

```
struct v2f
{
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

Comment: You're right. I tried using other shaders and scripts within the `UIEffects` framework. Everyone worked as expected except for the alpha. Every object using `UIEffects` glitches if it has some transparency, probably because iOS 15 changed something (just supposing). I'm gonna take a look over the shaders, maybe I can figure out something. Thanks for replying me, you made my day

Comment: In Shader, you may also look into "RenderType", "Blend"..etc. and "Clipping" for alpha..etc.

UI Shader with Alpha is compatible with iOS 15. However, writing a universal shader for "Many Devices" is not easy. for example, when you are working on webcam filter, you need to find a trick to make the result as similar as possible between High-End & Low-End devices.

Comment: Things are getting even more weird here! I decided to create my own basic Grayscale+Transparency Shader (mostly copied from a forum since I've never studied Shaders yet). And guess what? It gives me the exact issue on iOS 15+. Right now I think that the problem is not about UIEffect anymore, but something more general.

Comment: I FINALLY found what's going on, just by luck. Basically it's about the Dark Mode which somehow interferes with the Shader. I updated the whole question to make it clear. I literally don't know what's going on with this

Comment: It's a Well-Known Bug which is already been submitted. Thanks for your help and the patience @thelghome

Comment: Could you please post the issue tracker link so we can see when Unity fixes this bug ?

Comment: @Six91 Have you tried Unity2021.1.28f1 or above?
I think your issue is due to (Fallback "Standard"), and mismatching variable type "half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;". It should be float2 instead of half2.

You can remove the line of "Fallback...", if you don't want the shader changed by system.

Comment: @Six91 I updated my answer too, referring to your original shader code. It seems likely you are missing alpha value at all, and default value is 1.

Comment: @Angecroft [Here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/gameobjects-are-rendered-with-different-colors-in-the-ios-build) and [here](https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?1381781_30ohvm3utos67ain) you can find the info, this bug has been submitted more than once with different behavior, but apparently they belong to the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I experienced something similar, where materials (and presumably shades...) looked different in an IOS build with dark mode off compared to the editor or an IOS build with dark mode on.

From [here](https://akshay-s-somkuwar.medium.com/disable-dark-mode-in-ios-13-for-your-ios-app-c025b446d87b) a dirty hack until this bug is solved is to add this key to the info.plist:

```
UIUserInterfaceStyle = Dark
```

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOohF.png)

This basically forces the app to use dark mode. It works the same for

```
UIUserInterfaceStyle = Light
```